# Ionic - Search Results Under Searchbar

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I am using Ionic and Angular to create a grocery list app. The design I was given calls for a searchbar with results to display after a button is clicked. These results are another list that is directly underneath the searchbar and overlays the content of the page.

**Mockups**

[Before clicking button to show search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g4jrP.jpg)

[Desired look after clicking button to show search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EzxqW.png)

**So far, this is the code:**

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-grid>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-searchbar *ngIf="isOn"></ion-searchbar>
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item *ngFor="let searchresult of searchresults" (click)="selectresult(result)">
          {{ result.$value }}
        </ion-item>
      </ion-list>
      <ion-col>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col>
        <ion-buttons end>
          <button *ngIf="!isOn" (click)="showsearch()" ion-button small color="nudgetprim" end>
            + Add Item
          </button>
        </ion-buttons>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-grid>

  <ion-item-group>
    <ion-item-divider color="light">Items</ion-item-divider>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items | async" (click)="changestate(item)">{{item.$value}}</ion-item>
  </ion-item-group>

</ion-content>
```

I assumed that I could make this happen with:

```
   <ion-list>
    <ion-item *ngFor="let searchresult of searchresults" (click)="selectresult(result)">
      {{ result.$value }}
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>
```

but no success.

Right now, the searchbar is displaying properly after the button is clicked, I just need to find a way to have the listed results underneath where it is overlaying the previously displayed contents. How do I achieve this look in Ionic?

Answer (score 0):

Initialize *searchresults* property in your class:

```
searchresults: any[] = [];
```

It appears the property is undefined causing Angular to ignore bindings.

Please provide your .ts file for reference.